# When is the code section of an ELF loaded into memory?

Tags: linux, operating-system

When an executable in ELF format is run in a linux environment, at what point is the actual contents of the file loaded into physical memory?

Which part of the operating system is responsible for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a detailed article on LWN about this: https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/

In particular, code is loaded by `load_elf_binary()`: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c?v=3.18#L571

That function is called (indirectly) from `do_execve_common()` which is of course called from `execve()` and friends: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c?v=3.18#L1513

As you may already know, `execve()` and friends are usually called right after a new process is created (via `fork()`).  So there's very little in between "create a process" and "load the ELF."

Finally, the code is loaded from virtual to physical memory by the page fault handler which is invoked by a hardware exception from the MMU.

Comment: Well you and I covered two different aspects. Nice.

Comment: Thank you for that link. But the actual code segment of the binary would not be loaded until it first starts executing right? When the process tries to execute for the first time, it will page fault on the address of the first instruction. Isn't that when the actual file is loaded into the memory? (assuming this program is being run for the first time)

Comment: @MIkhail: When you ask "Isn't that when the actual file is loaded into the memory?" I guess you mean physical memory?  In that case I suppose you're right, the load into physical RAM might not occur until the last moment.

Comment: Yes. I was talking about physical RAM. In this case, who executes the code which loads this into physical RAM?

Comment: The kernel code to satisfy a page fault is invoked by the MMU (hardware).

Answer (score 2):

The kernel loads the ELF exe image wherever the image header says it goes. (We remember that Unix depends utterly on virtual memory to function correctly, see fork().) The kernel has routines for loading shared libraries; however these are rarely used except for the loader itself. The kernel then jumps to the start address specified in the image. If there is a loader, this jump is hijacked to jump into the loader.

Most shared libraries are loaded by the loader (/lib/ld-linux-so.2 for i386), which is a shared library. The loader can do things like locate where shared libraries are in the system instead of depend on absolute paths embedded in the exe image like the kernel has to do. The loader maps libraries into memory and performs fixups. The loader remains loaded in memory and can be used to load additional libraries on demand (see dlopen()).